# Cloud Functions Error: function is not a valid feature. Must be one of database,firestore,functions,hosting,storage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am being practiced to make TelegramBot using firebase cloud function.  installed firebase-tools, registered the firebase account and created a new sample project, but then I got an error when I selected the project.

This is the error message:

Function is not a valid feature. Must be one of database,firestore,functions,hosting,storage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How silly am i, it's typo...
all i need to do is to change execution syntax like below

> firebase init functions

with plural "s"